# Как сортировать хаотичный массив в порядке возрастания?

Tags: java, android

Есть коллекция из элементов с переменной

```
A=4  
B=1    
C=65  
D=6  
E=414
```

Надо их расположить в порядке возрастания. 1 4 6 65 414. Есть можно то покажите как использовать в коллекции без самодельных циклов.

Comment: Какой тип имеет эта коллекция, `Map<String, Integer>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда у вас будет массив используйте функцию

```
//заполняем массив...
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Примите к сведению что массивы и коллекции эти разные вещи. Не забудьте заимпоритировать пакет Arrays

Если вопрос касается коллекций, то следующий подход, например для ArrayList:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
//заполняем лист...
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: Но у него ведь коллекция... Наверно он и решение хочет для коллекции...

Comment: Он написал в вопросе "массив"

Comment: Ну ладно. Вообще сначала мне показалось, что это вопрос на написание собственного компаратора.

Comment: Так просто? а я думал щяс опять примеры с циклами пойдут)). Спасибо

Comment: Не пиши то что уже написанно. Один из принципов разработки ПО. Переписывать заново алгоритмы есть смысл только в учебных целях или если ты уверен что сможешь написать лучший алгоритм.